# LINQ query with multiple StartsWith clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that works as it is supposed to as follows,

```
var query = DataContext.TenantDataServerTables.Where(p => 
             p.Nursing_Home_Section == homeSection &&
             p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(@"ア") ||
             p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(@"イ") ||
             p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(@"ウ") ||
             p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(@"エ") ||
             p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(@"オ"));
        }
```

Is there a way to do something like this to streamline the query?

```
char[] array = new char[] { 'ア', 'イ', 'ウ', 'エ', 'オ' };

var query = DataContext.TenantDataServerTables.Where(p => 
                 p.Nursing_Home_Section == homeSection &&
                 p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(array));
```

This is just an example as there are many more characters that I have to check `StartsWith` on the LINQ query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As every string is nothing but an array of characters you could do any linq on it. Just use the very first character and check if it part of your array using [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var query = DataContext.TenantDataServerTables.Where(p => 
             p.Nursing_Home_Section == homeSection &&
             array.Contains(p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString()[0]));
```

Alternativly to `p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString()[0]` you can also use `p.Tenant_Kana_Last.First()` which is a bit easier to read.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but I don't how this `p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString()[0])` does anything? Isn't `[0]` just an indwx of an array? And doesn't `Contains` check anywhere in the string?

Comment: `ToString` creates a new string which *is* an array of `char`, by using index null you get the strings first character.

Comment: You can use the index operator `[]` on strings to get the char at the position. So `[0]` gives you the first char in the string.

Comment: @KyloRen here `[0]` means first character of string. `array` must contain all sets of characters you look for. `array = new char[] {'ア', 'イ', 'ウ'}`. finally the `Contains` will check if any of your characters in array matches with first character of `Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString()`.

Comment: Dammit, I missed that you put this in the query, `array.Contains` . Thanks your answer solved the issue.

Comment: English is not my strong point, could you edit the title to resemble more what the question is about?

Answer (score 7):

You can use your array of "starts" in [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) predicate, like this:

```
var array = new string[] {@"ア", @"イ", @"ウ", @"エ", @"オ"};
var query = DataContext.TenantDataServerTables.Where(p => 
    p.Nursing_Home_Section == homeSection &&
    array.Any(prefix => p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(prefix))
);
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error that `cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'`, I am unfamiliar with your code and I don't know how to remedy this?

Comment: @KyloRen Ah, I missed that your array is `char[]`. This method requires `string[]` (see edit). This approach lets you use prefixes of any length.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check for chars only, you can use HimBromBeere's approach. If the array should contain strings with more than one character, try this:

```
var query = DataContext.TenantDataServerTables.Where(p =>
    p.Nursing_Home_Section == homeSection &&
    array.Any(str => p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(str)));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var searchList = new List<string> { "ア", "イ", "ウ", "エ", "オ" };

            var fullNameList = new List<string>
            {
                "Alpha",
                "アBravo",
                "Charlie",
                "イDelta",
                "Echo",
                "エFoxtrot",
                "Golf"
            };

            var finds = from name in fullNameList
                        from firstName in searchList
                        where name.StartsWith(firstName)
                        select name;

            foreach (string str in finds)
                Console.WriteLine(str);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool idea, however you may consider some short explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace

```
p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(array)
```

with

```
array.Any( c => p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(c))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char[] array = new char[] { 'ア', 'イ', 'ウ', 'エ', 'オ' };
var query = DataContext.TenantDataServerTables
    .Where(p => p.Nursing_Home_Section == homeSection 
                && array
                    .Any(c=>p.Tenant_Kana_Last.ToString().StartsWith(c));
```

Any returns true if at least 1 matches the Truth, will work like your chained or operators