# Why is the delimiter excluded in this String.Join? C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` that I use for binding that I want to put into a `String.Join` statement, but I don't understand why it is giving the results I am getting and how to fix it?

This is the code I am using to get the result,

First I am getting the data I need via this LINQ query,

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetNursingHomeNames(string home)
{
    return DataContext.NursingHomeNameServerTables.Where(p => p.Nursing_Home_Section == home)
                        .Select(p => p.Nursing_Home_Name).Distinct();
}
```

I then put it into the `ObservableCollection<T>` (You may be wondering why I am not using an `ObservableCollection<T>` with the LINQ query, but I have my reasons.)

```
public static void NursingHomeNamesCollection(ObservableCollection<string> nursingHomeNames, string nursingHomeSection)
{
    var homeNames = GetNursingHomeNames(nursingHomeSection);
    if (homeNames == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (var item in homeNames)
    {
        nursingHomeNames.Add(item);
    }
}
```

This is the property in the main window,

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> NursingHomeNames { get; set; } =
                   new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Then

Than I use `Join` to get the results for a specific purpose I need,

```
var result = String.Join(@",", NursingHomeNames.ToList());
```

And this gives the following result where there is no delimiter only a space,

> foo bar bat baz

However, if just do this,

```
ObservableCollection<string> observableCol = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "foo", "bar", "bat", "baz" };

var result = String.Join(@",", observableCol.ToList());
```

The result is displayed with the delimiters in place.

> foo,bar,bat,baz

**Why is it doing this and is there a way to ensure the delimiters are correctly placed?**

I know I have to work on my naming conventions.

EDIT: In the debuger, this is what I see,

When assigning the collection to a variable named `data` and viewing the results in the `Watch Window`

```
var data = NursingHomeNames.ToList();
```

> Count = 4
>
> [0]  "foo"
>
> [1]  "bar"
>
> [2]  "bat"
>
> [3]  "baz"

However, I cannot reproduce this using any other code that does not use the LINQ query that pulls the data from the database. I tried making a new list and passing that list through the same code, but the error does not occur. I am sorry, but I can't post an example that can be reproduced.

Comment: am I missing something? How are you adding to that list from a static method?

Comment: Fire up a debugger and see that `NursingHomeNames.ToList()` returns just one string.

Comment: @DavidPilkington, sorry, I could not show all the code as I pass the `ObservableColection` as a parameter through a few classes, hence the strange code, the code was more to demonstrate how I was populating the  collection.

Comment: @KyloRen I see, that does pose a problem as we dont get the whole picture. M.Mimpen is correct though. Something else is joining those strings

Comment: Out of interest, why call observableCol.ToList() in your Join statement? ObservableCollection<T> implements IEnumerable<T> so you're just doing work to make a List<T> that is then discarded.

Comment: Do you have any extension methods kicking around which might have their own ToList() implementation that observableCol.ToList() is falling into?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We can't reproduce this. `string.Join()` doesn't do anything interesting other than enumerate the enumerator. Set breakpoints and inspect all the variables and method calls in between.

Comment: @DavidPilkington, I edited to what it should be.

Comment: @M.Mimpen, `NursingHomeNames.ToList()` gives 4 separate strings in the debuger.

Comment: @KyloRen instead of assuming there is something wrong with `String.Join` check your values. If you get `foo bar bat baz` it's because the list contains only a single string with that exact value. Perhaps that's what is stored in your database as well? What does `NursingHomeNames.Count()` return?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I just posted as you did, check my earler comment

Comment: @KyloRen are three of them empty perhaps? `String.Join(",",new List<string>{"foo","bar","bat","baz"})` returns `foo,bar,bat,baz`

Comment: Or, [given your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545966/linq-query-with-multiple-startswith-clause), your delimiter is actually a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) and gets applied to another character, so it won't appear alone.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, strings are not empty, I get a count of 4 and 4 separate strings.

Comment: Post a *reproducible* example then, that doesn't require access to your database and full code. As I just showed, if the list contained four strings, you'd get the expected result. Can you reproduce *your* results with a simple list that contains those strings and post the one-line code?

Comment: @Kylo I don't know why you're being so defensive at every comment, but obviously your problem as posted is not reproducible by us, so we have to guess at the actual problem. No, .NET's `string.Join()` nor `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` are broken, so the problem must be in your code or your data. For the last time, provide a [mcve] or this can't be answered. I know for a fact that my previous comment (combining Unicode characters) is actually a very sensible explanation for what you might be seeing, but **we can't see what you're seeing**.

Comment: @CodeCaster, sorry if I am coming off that way, that was not my intention, I am working on a sample as we speak. cheers

Comment: Great. You can do that by creating a `List<string>` containing some actual data from your database.

Comment: @KyloRen I'd read CodeCaster's comment very carefully. Are you using an actual comma or a different character that looks like a comma? This won't be the first case where someone used a Unicode character that looked like a comma but had a completely different behavior. Why did you use `@` to define the comma? It doesn't need escaping

Comment: This is string-specific, not Linq-specific. Once an enumerable enters `string.Join()`, it's just that: an enumerable. You should be able to create a [mcve] by copy-pasting actual values from your database into a new `List<string>`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I did that, but the results are different, as in, they are how they are supposed to be when I do it that way.

Comment: @NeilMoss, Sorry, I did not know you could do it that way, I will keep that in mind in future ,not to use `ToList()`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132815/discussion-on-question-by-kyloren-why-is-the-delimiter-excluded-in-this-string-j).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, after weeks of effort to figure this out, the answer to be had was with the comment that @Panagiotis Kanavos and @CodeCaster made.

I was using a Unicode character that looked like a comma and it was therefore creating a different behavior than what I was expecting.

Answer (score -4):

In method

```
public static void NursingHomeNamesCollection(string nursingHomeSection)
```

you get string parameter to input. After in this method scope you add this string into static collection, but **item** in this scope is a **char**.

```
foreach (var item in homeNames)
```

You're trying to add a character at a time and join one big string. You need get collection to input of this method.

Comment: `nursingHomeSection` is not the variable that is used in the `foreach()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster he is trying to add in `foreach()` operator `item` into string. And after then would want that he earned `Join()` on the collection of 1 item.

Comment: @Nikita Read the question again. `homeNames` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, hence `item` is a `string`.